# onfocus in a pop-up to remove the error

Tags: javascript, jquery

**pop.js**

```
 function register() {
    var lbox = new LadduBox();
    lbox.init({
        "width": 1287,
            "height": 635,
            "HTML": '<div class="LregisterI"><br><div class="close"><img src="' + img_loc + 'close.png" id="btnClose" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div><div class="Lregister"><form action="line_check.php" name="reg" method="POST" onsubmit="return chkform();"><table border="0" align="center" width="790" style=""><tr><td colspan="4"><img src="' + img_loc + 'reg.png" /></td></tr><tr><td align="" width="78">Name</td><td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="inputstyle" onfocus="document.getElementById(err1).innerHTML='';" /></td><td align="center">Gender</td><td><div class="gender"><div class="umale"><input type="radio" name="gender" checked value="Male"><label>Male</label></div><div class="ufemale"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"><label>Female</label></div></div></td></tr><tr><td align="" width="78"></td><td height="10"><div class="err" id="err1"></div></td><td align="center"></td><td><div class="err2"></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4"><div class="hline"></div></td></tr><tr><td height="10" colspan="4"></td></tr><tr><td align="">Email</td><td><input type="text"  id="email" name="email" class="inputstyle" /></td><td align="center">Collage</td><td><input type="text" id="college" name="college" value="" class="inputstyle" /></td></tr><tr><td align="" width="78"></td><td height="20"><div class="err" id="err2"></div></td><td align="center"></td><td><div class="err" id="err3"></div></td></tr><tr><td align="">Mobile</td><td><input type="text" id="no" name="number" value="" class="inputstyle" /></td><td align="center">City</td><td><input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" class="inputstyle" /></td></tr><tr><td align="" width="78"></td><td height="10"><div class="err" id="err4"></div></td><td align="center"></td><td><div class="err" id="err5"></div></td></tr><tr><td align="" width="78"></td><td colspan="3"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="" /></td></tr></table></form></div></div>',
            'btnCloseId': '#btnClose'
    });
    lbox.fire();
}
```

Its a form pop-up , when a user click on register button , it call the register() function and open the pop-up . Now the if the user without entering the data , click submit . error will show up in err1,err2,err3....  etc 
Suppose the err1 is for name , now i need if the user click on the textbox ,
**

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="inputstyle" onfocus="document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML='';" />**
```

It will remove the error which has id err1 but it's showing me the error (**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string** )

so please any one can give me the solution

Comment: I suggest you to reformat your code up there, it's a little bit hard to read. : )

Comment: That string literal is insane. Surely its HTML could be moved to an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should add the '' in you getElementById paramter like this:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="document.getElementById(err1).innerHTML='';" />
```

=>

```
<input type="text" onfocus="document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML='';" />
```

Hope this would solve your problem. : )

Comment: The reason for the same error is you use the ' to wrap your whole html . But you use '' in onfocus statement. You'd better change your quotation mark. Here is demo:    '<div class="LregisterI"><input type="text" onfocus="document.getElementById(\'err1\').innerHTML=\'\';" /></div>

Answer (score 0):

This not getting SyntaxError: `<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="inputstyle" onfocus="document.getElementById(err1).innerHTML=" " "/>`
And I formatted in:

```
function register() {
    var lbox = new LadduBox();
    lbox.init({
        "width": 1287,
        "height": 635,
        "html": 
            '<div class="LregisterI">'+
            '<br>'+
            '<div class="close">'+
                '<img src=+ img_loc + "close.png" id="btnClose" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>'+
            '<div class="Lregister">'+
                '<form action="line_check.php" name="reg" method="POST" onsubmit="return chkform();">'+
                    '<table border="0" align="center" width="790" style="">'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td colspan="4">'+
                                '<img src="' + img_loc + 'reg.png" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td align="" width="78">Name</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="inputstyle" onfocus="document.getElementById(err1).innerHTML=" " "/>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td align="center">Gender</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="gender">'+
                                    '<div class="umale">'+
                                        '<input type="radio" name="gender" checked value="Male">'+
                                        '<label>Male</label>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="ufemale">'+
                                        '<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">'+
                                        '<label>Female</label>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td align="" width="78"></td>'+
                            '<td height="10">'+
                                '<div class="err" id="err1"></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td align="center"></td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="err2"></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td colspan="4">'+
                                '<div class="hline"></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td height="10" colspan="4"></td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td align="">Email</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="inputstyle" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td align="center">Collage</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="college" name="college" value="" class="inputstyle" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td align="" width="78"></td>'+
                            '<td height="20">'+
                                '<div class="err" id="err2"></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td align="center"></td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="err" id="err3"></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td align="">Mobile</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="no" name="number" value="" class="inputstyle" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td align="center">City</td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" class="inputstyle" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td align="" width="78"></td>'+
                            '<td height="10">'+
                                '<div class="err" id="err4"></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td align="center"></td>'+
                            '<td>'+
                                '<div class="err" id="err5"></div>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td align="" width="78"></td>'+
                            '<td colspan="3">'+
                                '<input type="submit" class="submit" value="" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</table>'+
                '</form>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>',
        'btnCloseId': '#btnClose'
    });
    lbox.fire();
}
```

Hope this will solve you problem.